# getting my back and forwards buttons to work with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My site is working much quicker thanks to some code I painstakingly modified, but I would love if the browsers' back/forwards buttons worked. Right now, with my code below, the browser address bar never changes. When someone clicks 'Back', it takes them out of the application.

Would there by any easy way of changing this so the browser's back/forward button worked? Or else if someone could point me in the right direction. Thanks for any help.

```
$(document).on("ready", function () {

    //I want to load content into the '.page-content' class, with ajax

    var ajax_loaded = (function (response) {

        $(".page-content")

        .html($(response).filter(".page-content"));

        $(".page-content .ajax").on("click", ajax_load);


    });



    //the function below is called by links that are described 
    //with the class 'ajax', or are in the div 'menu' 

    var history = [];

    var ajax_load = (function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();


        history.push(this);
        var url = $(this).attr("href");
        var method = $(this).attr("data-method");


        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: method,
            success: ajax_loaded
        });

    });


    //monitor for clicks from menu div, or with
    //the ajax class
    //why the trigger?

    $("#menu a").on("click", ajax_load);
    $(".ajax").on("click", ajax_load);
    $("#menu a.main").trigger("click");



});
```

Comment: Yes. History.js - it pushes browser states and allows for back and forward movement

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way of detecting what you are asking.

Bear in my playing with the back and forward buttons is a risky task.

```
window.onload = function () {

    if (typeof history.pushState === "function") {

        history.pushState("someState", null, null);

        window.onpopstate = function () {

            history.pushState("newState", null, null);

            // Handle the back (or forward) buttons here
            // Will not handle refresh, use onbeforeunload for this.
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, but not sure how to implement it. Surely the commented '//Handle the back (or forward) buttons here' is the code I'm looking for? What do you mean by 'Bear in my playing with the back and forward buttons is a risky task.'? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the jquery address plugin (http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/).
It has an event that detects when the user presses the back/forward button.

```
$.address.externalChange(function() { console.log('back/forward pressed'); });
```

As far as I know there is no way of differentiating between back and forward.

Comment: Cheers, will check it out. I think history.js might be too vast for what I need - all my ajax is working, just those pesky back/forwards buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely check [History.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/)
Here's some sample code:-

```
  (function(window,undefined){

    // Prepare
    var History = window.History; // Note: We are using a capital H instead of a lower h
    if ( !History.enabled ) {
         // History.js is disabled for this browser.
         // This is because we can optionally choose to support HTML4 browsers or not.
        return false;
    }

    // Bind to StateChange Event
    History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function(){ // Note: We are using statechange instead of popstate
      var State = History.getState(); // Note: We are using History.getState() instead of event.state
      //History.log(State.data, State.title, State.url);
      var goto_url = State.url;            
      $.ajax({
          url: goto_url,
          dataType: "script"
      });
    });
  })(window);
```